# How to conveniently perform PCA inverse transform on lesser number of components?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I am exploring structure of data and plotting explained variance by components. Therefore I perform PCA with number of components equal to number of dimensions. Is there a way to perform inverse transform using less number of components?
Something like

```
data = np.random.rand(100, 10) # data of size (N_objects, n_dim)
pca = sklearn.decomposition.PCA(n_dim)
transformed = pca.fit_transform(data)
# then I want to see restoration by different numbers of components
new_data_1 = pca.inverse_transform(transformed, use_components = n_dim // 2)
new_data_2 = pca.inverse_transform(transformed, use_components = n_dim // 3)
new_data_3 = pca.inverse_transform(transformed, use_components = n_dim // 4)
```

The problem is, `inverse_transform` method does not have parameter `use_components`, so I wonder if there is a way to do such thing elegantly? Or I have to retrain `PCA` object with different number of components each time?

Comment: Hi @Nourless, that was a good question. Could you consider replacing `data = get_some_data()` with something reproducible? For example `data = np.random.rand(100, 10)` as in my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the transformed data, set the last n components to 0, then inverse transform. Here you have a reproducible example.

```
from numpy.random import rand
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

# PCA transform
data = rand(100, 10)
n_dim = data.shape[1]
pca = PCA(n_dim)
transformed = pca.fit_transform(data)

# Inverse PCA
def inverse_pca(pca_data, pca, remove_n):
    transformed = pca_data.copy()
    transformed[:, -remove_n:] = 0 
    return pca.inverse_transform(transformed)

new_data = inverse_pca(transformed, pca, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to selectively zero out the components vectors:

```
data = get_some_data() # data of size (N_objects, n_dim)
pca = sklearn.decomposition.PCA(n_dim)
transformed = pca.fit_transform(data)

all_components = pca.components_.copy()

to_zero = np.arange(n_dim//2, n_dim)
pca.components_[to_zero] = np.zeros_like(pca.components_[to_zero])
new_data_1 = pca.inverse_transform(transformed)

# restore original components
pca.components_ = all_components.copy()
# repeat with the other to_zero values
```

**NOTE**: It is important to zero out the vectors from the end of the matrix up (PCA sorts the vectors according to the explained variance)